# Which event handler should I use to customize the Cancel button in Edit form in sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I want to add a event receiver to "Cancel" button for "Edit Form" without using form action button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any Event receiver for what you want, you can go through list of event receivers by MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408183.aspx)

However you can create a custom Edit form for that specific document library with your own custom code for cancel button,

you can also look at these similar posts

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/1d32625e-1526-44a0-bcdd-287aca19247c

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/sharepoint2010programming/thread/6565d4e9-ae0c-4b7b-91b0-e586b91a7f04